# ERROR: Out of global stack in mastermind game

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to implement a mastermind game, the rules can be found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game).

The program generates a sequence of four distinct colors.
The player has 10 turns to guess the code.

I know that the code can be improved, but for now I'm trying to solve an out of global stack error. It occurs when I count the number of white pegs, but not always.  Probably the problem is in the common or distinct predicate (or both).

I'm a beginner in Prolog and I appreciate any help.

Please find the code on https://github.com/kmdeoliv/mastermind

Comment: It's a bit impolite to point at a repo; it's better to include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Preparing a minimal example would probably help you isolate the problem and probably make both of our lives easier.

Comment: Not an answer exactly but some of your predicates have standard counterparts: `member1/2` is `memberchk/2`, I would use `sort/2` instead of `distinct/2`, `nonmember/2` I would replace with `\+ member(...)`. You use `!` enough to make me nervous, but I didn't see obvious errors there. Beyond that, it doesn't look awful; I would use more powerful formatting predicates and separate the logic from the presentation more, but for a beginner this looks very good.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `member1` with `memberchk` and your code will work a lot better. The reason why will surprise you! Let's add some "debugging printfs" to your `member1/2` predicate:

```
member1(X,[H|_]) :- format('testing ~w == ~w?~n', [X,H]), X==H,!.
member1(X,[_|T]) :- format('looking in tail ~w for ~w~n', [T,X]), member1(X,T).
```

Seems to work OK, right?

```
?- member1(bar, [foo,bar,baz]).
testing bar == foo?
looking in tail [bar,baz] for bar
testing bar == bar?
true.
```

Incidentally, `memberchk/2` does the same thing:

```
?- memberchk(bar, [foo,bar,baz]).
true.
```

Well, we get "true". :) But what happens if I pass it something weird, like a variable instead of a list?

```
?- memberchk(bar, V).
V = [bar|_G483709].
```

Ah, well, `memberchk/2` is taking this as some kind of assertion that it's at the top of the list (this is because it does what `member/2` does but with only one solution). What does `member1/2` do?

```
?- member1(bar, V).
looking in tail _G478121 for bar
testing bar == _G478129?
looking in tail _G478130 for bar
testing bar == _G478138?
looking in tail _G478139 for bar
testing bar == _G478147?
looking in tail _G478148 for bar
testing bar == _G478156?
looking in tail _G478157 for bar
testing bar == _G478165?
looking in tail _G478166 for bar
testing bar == _G478174?
looking in tail _G478175 for bar
testing bar == _G478183?
...
eventually, boom, stack depth exceeded
```

Surprisingly, your code actually enters this case! Notice that you have conditions that define variables on one side but not the other:

```
(B1==B2 -> K is J + 1; K is J + 0, LB1=[B1],LB2=[B2]),
```

What values do `LB1` and `LB2` assume if B1 is not equal to B2? They remain uninstantiated! Then a few lines later you *unconditionally* append them:

```
append(LA1,LB1,AB1),
append(LC1,LD1,CD1),
append(AB1,CD1,L1),
```

So by this point, L1 = LA1 + LB1 + LC1 + LD1, but LB1 is a pure variable! This can happen to **any** of your LX1/LX2 variables, and then you wind up entering `member1/2` with some kind of hole in your list!

This is not a bug in Prolog, by the way. There are times when you want to leave the tail of a list uninstantiated—difference lists, for instance.

Now, I have buckets of other advice for you but I think the moral of the story right now is that you should use built-in predicates whenever possible. :)